# How to add syntax highlighter to a code fetched with a blogger api in android?

Tags: java, android, json, blogger, google-blogger-api

I want to make an android app for my [blog](https://devtejas.me) hosted on blogger but it includes some codes in the posts gor which I use prism syntax highlighter on web. But when I fetch the data to mobile app using the blogger api I have to parse it so the code also comes as a plain text. Which makes the post unreadable on an app.

Is there any way I can fix it or add custom styling to only the text in  tag using css or any other android library.